# Json string[] to Bitmask Conversion

Tags: c#, sqlite, json.net, .net-core-2.1

I have a web service which is returning a JSON object containing a string array. I've handled the object via Json.NET:

```cs
    public partial class Token
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("permissions")]
        public string[] Permissions { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to convert the `Permissions` string array to an Enum and store the resulting bitmask into a BLOB column in a sqlite database. I have the Enum constructed as such:

```cs
        [Flags]
        public enum Rights : uint
        {
            none= 0,
            read = 1,
            write = 2,
            modify = 4,
            [... etc ...]
        }
```

What is the proper way to parse a string array into a bitmask (int) for storage into the database?

What I will be doing is grabbing the bitmask from the database then using .HasFlag to determine if the proper permission was granted in the token.

I'm open for better ways to accomplish this, as well.

Answer (score 0):

To convert list of string values to single value of flags you can combine `Enum.Parse` (to convert string to enum) and `Aggregate` to *or* all flags together:

```
string[] permissions = new[]{"read", "write"};
Rights r = permissions
         .Select(x => (Rights)Enum.Parse(typeof(Rights), x)) // parse string to enum
         .Aggregate((cur,next) => cur | next); // merge all into single value
```

Note: if you can't guarantee that values are actually always valid use `Enum.TryParse` instead of `Parse` and have some default.